# how to display numbers of value in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Few days ago I've written some JavaScript about getting some data from JSON and it successfully output on console.log.
Now I want to output values on a HTML document, try to do with a button which can refresh the data ( like I click it it request again and get new data).

The problem I facing now is , I need to output numbers of data on one line.

OUTPUT EXAMPLE:(Time), (URL), (views)
Line 1 20200406 , www.XXX.com , 2000 
Line 2 20200406 , www.YYY.com , 5000 
Line 3 20200406 , www.YZZ.com , 9000

if I using 
`document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = String({a,b,c}) ;`
it only output var c

Will it be better if i use textarea ?

Thankyou.

```js
var a='';
var b='';
var c='';



function clickme() {
  for(var i=0; i<3 ;i++){
    a=a++;
    b=b++;
    c=+b;
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = String({a,b,c}) ;
   }
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <head>
        <title>Check UAT4 & UAT8 Version</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="test">
            <button type="button" onClick="clickme()">Click to Test</button>
            <p id= "p1" >testing</p1>
            <p id= "p2" >2222222</p2>
        </div>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `JSON.stringify({a,b,c})` instead of `String({a,b,c})`

```js
var a=0, b=0,  c=0;
function clickme() {
  let htmlString ='';
  for(var i=0; i<3 ;i++){
    a++;
    b++;
    c=+b;
    htmlString = htmlString + JSON.stringify({a,b,c}) + '<br>'
    }
     document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML =htmlString ;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <div id="test">
            <button type="button" onClick="clickme()">Click to Test</button>
            <p id= "p1" >testing</p1>
            <p id= "p2" >2222222</p2>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thankyou! Could I ask one more question? In the code I try to use `for` to output 3 lines of record, but it only gives the first line . Where did i get wrong? Shouldn't it print 3 times?

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple nodes you have to `create them and append to your div`.

Do something like following to output 3 (or n) lines in div:

```js
var a='', b='',  c='';
function clickme() {
  for(var i=0; i<3 ;i++){
    a=a++;
    b=b++;
    c=+b;
    var el = "p"+(i+2)
    var node = document.createElement("p");                 
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify({a,b,c}));         
    node.appendChild(textnode);                              
    document.getElementById("test").appendChild(node); 
    }
   
}
```

```html
    <body>
        <div id="test">
            <button type="button" onClick="clickme()">Click to Test</button>
            <p id= "p1" >testing</p>
            <p id= "p2" >2222222</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you ! I will try it out !